# All in one Exchange Server for small domain

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007

Is deploying a Exchange 2007 Server (Standard Edition) with all roles on one machine a supported configuration? It seems that this is the default option in a SBS / EBS scenario but I'm already invested in Windows Server 2003 Standard domain. I'm in a SMB environment with around 40 users. I'm currently using a hosted provider, but the monthly fee has grown so much that I could lease a really nice machine for less money. The Outlook connections' bandwidth is no joke either.

I'm thinking I would have to setup this all-in-one server on the LAN and make some very specific rules on my firewall. All the Microsoft documentation I can find seems to imply multiple servers. Does anyone here have advice on setting up an all-in-one Exchange box and whether this is supported?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows Small Business Server 2008 runs all Exchange roles on a single machine, along with being a file server, domain controller, SharePoint server, kitchen sink, etc. It works fine.

Microsoft doesn't *recommend* this configuration for non-SBS environments, and you may well find issues for which the SBS product has had enginnering invested specifically to resolve, but it can be made to work. I'm running Exchange 2007 on a Windows 2003 domain controller computer at one Customer site (where I was budget-limited and had no choice) and it works fine.

Forward incoming SMTP and HTTP / HTTPS through your firewall for Exchange to accept incoming email and host ActiveSync / OWA and you'll be fine.

Comment: @Evan Thanks for sharing your experience, that's the kind of information I was looking for.